# Disable the input field if corresping search field is Empty

Tags: html, angularjs

I have following input fields in the search Page.

1. Column
2. Operator
3. ValueToSearch

Currently Operator holds the value "IsEmpty". I wanted to disable the ValueToSearch since Operator value is Empty. If operator is other than IsEmpty (eg. equals, not equals) then i should show ValueToSearch.

How to disable if condition is not true.?

```
<div ng-if="query.field.operatorClass == 'ComparableOrNull' || query.field.operatorClass == 'IntOrNull'" class="ng-scope">
    <!-- ngIf: selectedOperator[$index] == translatedIsEmpty -->
    <!-- ngIf: selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty -->
    <input ng-if="selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty" blur-integer="" ng-model="query.value" class="form-control ng-valid ng-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">
    <!-- end ngIf: selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty -->
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)  and [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive!

Check out this :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  Column : <input ng-model="column" /> <br/>
  Operator : <input ng-init="operator=''" ng-model="operator" /> <br/>
  Value To Search : <input ng-model="valueToSearch" ng-disabled="operator==''" />
</div>
```

---

To hide you can use ngIf :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-init="translatedIsEmpty=''" ng-repeat="op in ['+','','*']">
    Column :
    <input ng-model="column" />
    <br/>Operator :
    <input ng-model="op" />
    <br/>Value To Search :
    <input ng-if="op != translatedIsEmpty"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added operator is equal to empty.. <input ng-if="selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty" ng-disabled="selectedOperator[$index] == translatedIsEmpty" blur-integer ng-model="query.value" class="form-control" />. It is not working as said.

Comment: Why have you put ngIf and ngDisabled? You want to disable or hide the field?

Comment: Hi Himanshu, i have full block for input field..can you please check that how to hide/disable this input field if operator is "IsEmpty"